# How does display:none; effect css for mobile devices?

Tags: css, mobile-safari, mediaelement

If we have hidden some stuff using display:none; for example: images , will it still be downloaded by rendering engine? If yes, does that mean while opening the same web page in mobile, it's going to be unnecessary extra weight to download?

This can further mean that modifying the same webpage for mobile can be a bad idea. Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the entire page is downloaded (hidden elements and all).  The `display:none` is meaningless until the page has been processed by the browser's CSS Engine.

Comment: You probably know more about this than I do, but would it not be a very reasonable optimization for browsers not to download images until requested from not-`none`'d DOM elements? Do you have a reference to show this is really never done by browsers?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't, and don't have a chance to conduct any tests of my own at the moment.  I think most designers/developers wouldn't want to delay loading of images which are hidden until they are unhidden as this would produce a "flicker" effect while the image is request, a short delay at page load is better than during use.  Having said that, I can see why this may be useful for mobile browsers... but I have a feeling that it would be up to the developer to only include the image when it was needed. (ie, dynamically adding an image img tag when its needed, instead of showing it).

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Do you recommend any other way to strip down extra content from web page to optimise it for mobile? If everything is getting downloaded and the subject in picture is iPhone, the whole content can be easily served after optimisation and there is no need of display:none.

Comment: I'm not used to mobile development, off the top of my head, maybe something like the [endless scrolling](http://uipatternfactory.com/p=endless-scrolling/ "endless scrolling") ui pattern?  Sorry, cant be of much more help in that area.

Comment: Anyone else with more ideas please? This thing is pretty much a bottleneck for one of the major decision I've to take for a client. Thanks.

Comment: It might be worth starting a new question as I'd argue it was an entirely different topic.  Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to stop an image being downloaded, wether the image is inline or is a background image within a CSS style, or wether it is being brought in through a media query. It works for nearly all mobile devices (except 'Fennec 10.0+' being the only device that still downloaded the image.- see Tim Kadle's test results)

Tim Kadlec's 'Media Query & Asset Downloading Test Results' research at:

http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

It says, for a background image, hide the parent element. If you can’t do that, then use a media query to set the background-image to only download when screen or device size is at certain size. Just define what you want hidden / to not download by putting inside media queries. Isn't it marvellous.

Also another brilliant test to use, so simple, at:
http://timkadlec.com/mq/test4.php

On this test you just resize your browser window to mimic wether 'desktop' or 'mobile' to see wether it is downloading images related to the media queries. You simply click the links for each scenario you want to test.